# Google Rewards for in-game purchasing

Tags: google-play-games

I have several gmail account each has its own rewards account. How can I use the accumulated rewards dollars for "in-game" purchases?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about your Google Play Store balance, you can pick that as an option from the payment dropdown on your device the same way you would pick one of your credit cards, or carrier billing. However, in my experience you have to have a balance large enough to cover the entire purchase -- you can't split it between store credit and another type of payment.